# What is the schema of Kerberos database?

Tags: kerberos

I dumped a kerberos database with

```
$ kdb5_util dump /User/user/kerberos/dbdump
```

In the file, each line has information of principals as

```
princ   38  23  4   3   0   PRINCIPAL@REALM 4224    86400   604800  0   0   0   1618454069  0   3   40  XXX 2   25  XXX 8   2   0100    1   4   XXX 1   7   18  62  XXX 1   7   17  46  XXX 1   7   16  54  XXX -1;
```

However, I cannot figure out what each column means.

I want to find locked principals from this database.

How can I get the schema of a dumped kerberos database?

Answer (score 1):

I sent an email to kerberos, and it says that supporting a document of the full dump file is on a todo list.

Instead, it suggests to use tabdump, which supports various dumptypes: https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-devel/doc/admin/admin_commands/kdb5_util.html#tabdump